# Why is this element not stacking according to its z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

Everything else is stacking fine, and I just can't figure out why the `<span>` tooltip on `<a>` 1 doesn't stack in front of `<a>` 3, when `<a>` 2 stacks fine in front of `<a>` 1 in almost the exact same situation.

codepen: http://codepen.io/briligg/pen/epqNLd?editors=110

abbreviated HTML

```
 <div class=" darkYellow100 pix">
    <a class="numbers tooltipTL" style="top: 70%; left: 50%;">
            1
          <span style="z-index: 10;">
          Talk 
          </span>
   </a>
   <a class="numbers tooltipBL" style="top: 51%; left: 65%;">
            2
          <span>
          Talk
          </span>
  </a>
  <a class="numbers tooltipB" style="top: 32.5%; left: 30%;">
            3
          <span style="z-index: 10;">
          Talk
          </span>
  </a>
  <a class="numbers tooltipB" style="top: 58%; left: 75%;">
            4
          <span>
          Talk
          </span>
  </a>
  <img class="buttontop" src="http://www.moonwards.com/img/Cernan's-Promise-Longshot.jpg" alt="Teacup crater with first structures">
</div>
```

abbreviated CSS

```
a.tooltipTL {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
}

a.tooltipTL span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: justify;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a:hover.tooltipTL span {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  bottom: 30px;
  left: -325px;
  z-index: 10;
}
a.tooltipBL {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
}
a.tooltipBL span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: justify;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a:hover.tooltipBL span {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.darkYellow100 {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 0, 0.7);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.pix {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `z-index` of the children `span` elements doesn't make a difference when their parent elements have the same `z-index` and are participating in the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

For example, anchor element number one and anchor element number three both have a `z-index` of `8`. Since they have the same `z-index`, they stack based on their order in the DOM. In this case, anchor element number three appears *after* anchor element number one, which means that it will appear above anchor element one and the tooltip.

If you want the `span` element's `z-index` to be respected, you need to remove the `z-index` from the parent anchor elements. In doing so, the stacking will be based on the `span` element's `z-index` (since the parent elements aren't being stacked).

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVXEjv)

Of course, you could also just change the `z-index` of the parent elements.

```
a.tooltipTL {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

..or you could re-order the DOM elements based on how you want them to stack ([example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaNKqL)).

Comment: Removing the z-index of the anchors did it. I'm surprised - why wouldn't they be behind the image? But i'll take it. Maybe i should do a thorough browser compatibility test...

Comment: @kimholder They don't appear behind the `img` element because they are absolutely positioned, whereas the `img` element is set to `position: static` by default. If you were to add `position: relative` to the `img` element, then it would appear *above* the anchor elements since it appears after them in the DOM and none of them have `z-index`s anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just a z-index issue, you can fix it removing all 'z-index: 8;' from the css.

```
`http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpVoXE?editors=110`
```